# SQL search in relations

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a main table with two relations.

Data structure and example:

```
A/Employee
id  fields
1   Mike Miller
2   Lisa Miller

B/Skill
aid name
1   SQL
1   PHP

C/Language
aid name
1   German
```

I need a query which shows results from the main table and searches for a keyword in the relation tables.

> Search for Miller -> Mike Miller, Lisa Miller
>   Search for SQL -> Mike Miller
>   Search for German -> Mike Miller

There are 10.000 rows in the main table and 100.000 relations. 
I tried it with `JOIN` but the query is really slow.

Also the same row from the main table is displayed a view several times when there are more than one relations for this row:

> Search for Miller
>   Returns: Mike Miller, Mike Miller

(Mike Miller displayed more than one time)

```
SELECT fields 
FROM A 
JOIN B ON id = B.aid JOIN C ON id = C.aid 
WHERE fields LIKE '%"+$search+"%' OR B.name LIKE '%"+$search+"%' OR C.name LIKE '%"+$search+"%'"
```

I tried to fix the second problem with `DISTINCT` but now rows without relations are not displayed.

**I want to display every row from the main table exactly one time**. Which query do I need?

Comment: could you give us an example of your expected result?

Comment: LIKE is a slow way to search since indexes aren't used.

Comment: LIKE may be quite slow. To improve the efficiency, you may use MATCH with FULLTEXT INDEX instead. http://makandracards.com/makandra/12813-performance-analysis-of-mysql-s-fulltext-indexes-and-like-queries-for-full-text-search

Comment: does this really have to be 1 query? can your application not distinguish wether they are searching for a language, employee or skill? This would deffinitely boost performance when seperately made into 3 queries and it would make your sql a lot easier aswell

Comment: Where is this being used? You could do some of this on the client side?

Comment: I want to have only one searchbar for every type of search

Comment: How can I do this on client side?

Comment: according to your example does it mean that Mike Miller has sql, php as skills and uses german as his language? Also if you are looking for distinct it's only not showing results because they do not match your criteria right? so what exactly is the problem then?

Comment: Yes, in my Example Mike Miller has sql and php as skills. My problem is: when I search for Miller, the first query displays Mike Miller more than one time and the second query does not display Lisa Miller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your first query, as you mention yourself, is that you get several duplicate rows returned. Not strange, since I guess the relation between table A and table B & C is *one-to-many*.

In your next attempt you added *DISTINCT*, and that will indeed get rid off the duplicates, but the regular *join* (or inner join) will only return matches where data can be joined, i.e. where data exists in both joined tables.

**Introducing `LEFT JOIN`**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fields 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON id = B.aid 
LEFT JOIN C ON id = C.aid 
WHERE fields LIKE '%"+$search+"%' OR B.name LIKE '%"+$search+"%' OR C.name LIKE '%"+$search+"%'"
```

This will always search all data from table A, and those from table B & C where joins can be made. The DISTINCT will make sure that only unique rows are returned. You could also use GROUP BY for the same result, but that's usually used for aggregate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN`.

Example:

```
SELECT distinct e.empname FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN skill s ON s.aid = e.id
LEFT JOIN lang l ON l.aid = e.id 
WHERE e.empname LIKE '%Miller%' OR s.name LIKE '%Miller%' OR l.name LIKE '%Miller%'
```

Proof [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/4d6f1/6/0)